# How to get MS Office version using JScript in TestComplete?

Tags: ms-office, jscript, testcomplete

In TestComplete, how can we get Microsoft Office version (not Excel or Word) using JScript without looking into registry? I tried this (using the `Shell.Application` to get the Program files path) but it doesn't work:

```
var ProgramFiles = aqEnvironment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles", true);
var MSOffFilePath = ProgramFiles +"\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\";
var Officeversion = aqFileSystem.GetFileInfo(MSOffFilePath).VersionInfo.FileMajorVersion;
Log.Message(Officeversion);
```

Comment: We need more details. What environment are you running Javascript in? What did you try so far?

Comment: Using it in TestComplete.

Comment: var ProgramFiles = aqEnvironment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles", true);
var MSOffFilePath = ProgramFiles +"\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\";
    var Officeversion = aqFileSystem.GetFileInfo(MSOffFilePath).VersionInfo.FileMajorVersion;
    Log.Message(Officeversion);

Comment: I copied your code into your question - don't post code in comments: it is unreadable there.

Comment: see if this will help you - https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/other/officeVersion.bat

Answer (score 0):

You can use WMI for that. Query the [`Win32_Product`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378(v=vs.85).aspx) class to get installed Office products, the product names (for example, "Microsoft Office Standard 2010") and versions ("14.0.7015.1000").

```js
var oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:");

// Find all installed products whose name starts with "Microsoft Office"
// but ignore items like "Microsoft Office Proof (English)"
// or "Microsoft Office Office 64-bit Components 2010"
var colSoft = oWMI.ExecQuery(
  "SELECT * FROM Win32_Product"
  + " WHERE Name LIKE 'Microsoft Office%'"
  + " AND NOT Name LIKE '%(%'"
  + " AND NOT Name LIKE '%Proof%'"
  + " AND NOT Name LIKE '%Components%'"
);

if (colSoft.Count == 0) {
  Log.Message("Microsoft Office is not installed.");
}
else {
  var enumSoft = new Enumerator(colSoft);
  var item, strName;
  for (; !enumSoft.atEnd(); enumSoft.moveNext())
  {
    item = enumSoft.item();
    Log.Message(item.Name);    // Microsoft Office Standard 2010
    Log.Message(item.Version); // 14.0.7015.1000
  }
}
```